# No sound in ubuntu 17.10 with Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio

Tags: sound

I have Ubuntu 17.10 in my PC. but sound is not working. audio provider is Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio. did the latest software updates but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer:
open terminal and type "sudo apt install pavucontrol"

open the pavucontrol and click the ">" sign until you found configurations tab

select "Analog stereo duplex (unplugged)"

now close the app and you are done.

(if you only have headphones; go to the "output devices" tab and select headphones from the drop down)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The proposed "solution" really doesn't address the root problem, which is that sound only comes out of the internal speakers when either the headphones are plugged in (which you definitely DON'T want) or when you have Headphones selected for output but no headphones plugged in (also not desirable).